# Run Solr Docker Image on two different ports in a machine at same time

Tags: docker, solr

Is there a way to run Solr Docker Image on two different ports in a machine at same time?

I was referring this: https://hub.docker.com/_/solr but didn't find much regarding my use case. Can anyone suggest a solution to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Do

```
docker run -p 8983:8983 -d solr
docker run -p 8984:8983 -d solr
```

and you'll have one instance on http://localhost:8983/ and one on http://localhost:8984/